# Use curl to get a specific div from a web page

Tags: php, html, curl

I have a page being generated by from an rss feed, but it is being generated with additional `html`, `head`, and `body` tags. I would like to get only one `div` and it's contents from that page and load it into my page. I figured I would need to use `curl` to load from the page and I found many examples of loading the entire page, but how can I load only the specific div I am looking for?

Comment: After you scrapped the content with curl use regexp to find that specific div tag.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, no reason to use curl for a simple page download, just use:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

After that you have 2 options:

1. Use a [DOM Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to parse the HTML into a DOM tree, and use it to retrieve the specific element. This only works well if the page is relatively valid HTML.
2. Use a regexp or `strpos` and `substr` to find the specific part of the code you care about.

Purists usually hate on option 2, because it is inherently inferior to the first on a lot of aspects. It is however also much less work to code and for bad source code most probably more reliable. Which option you want to use is up to you - for a simple one-off case I'd definitely go for the simple approach and use a regexp if you know them, or `strpos` if you don't.